# Orchard CMS simple user registration/authentication

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, orchardcms

I think creating a simple user-registration on Orchard CMS should be easy?

What I need is a simplest set of steps that need to be followed to use basic user   registration/authentication in my test app, something similar to http://orchardproject.net/gallery/Users/Account/Register.
I've been scanning through google results on this, but most only talk of customization through external modules, I dont think I'll need external modules for a simple user authentication mechanism?

[Register/ Login/ Membership module in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948032/register-login-membership-module-in-orchard) link didn't help me much, as in, how do I get my users register/login after this setting? What do I need to do for this? Note, for now, I dont need customizations like, [Orchard: Custom Registration fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263739/orchard-custom-registration-fields).

From my understanding this should be a very simple thing to implement, but I've been struggling to get this my test app. What am I missing? Some guidance on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with activating Settings / Users / Users can create new accounts on the site ?

Comment: I have activated that. Now to able to present a form like http://orchardproject.net/gallery/Users/Account/Register to the users, do I need to create new html widgets? How do I handle/add the code that need to be called when the user clicks "Register"? How do I handle the "Sign In" code? I'm using Orchard specifically for its code extensibility features, so I would want to know how do I handle these parts of the code (that is the objective going ahead)

Comment: You don't have to add any code. Once you've activated this, the sign-in/register code that is already there is activated. Not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: Phew! Finally I see the "Register" link after I click "Sign In" link on my test site. I'm going dig down into the code, to see how I can customize this as per my requirements. If you can point out some code-parts or links that will help me customize the register/sign-in code, it would be of great! 
Thanks for you help!

Comment: Enabling shape tracing should give you all the pointers you need :)

Comment: @Karuna Sorate ... bit late to reply but did you ever find out how to edit the existing register form? (from the home page).... I would like to add additional fields..address etc...

Comment: I know this is late but just in case anyone else comes across it. You just need to use the shape tracing to create the cshtml override for you but for completeness just copy over the Orchard.Users\Views\Register.cshtml file into your themes view folder